# Variable declared but not initialized: what happens?

Tags: c++

What happens when a variable of some arbitrary class is defined but not initialized? I'm trying to understand what the compiler tries in such circumstances (use default constructor? just allocate memory? etc.)

---

Background info:

I've recently been using a library where something happens when the variable is declared but not set e.g.:

```
SomeClass x;
```

This causes problems with I create member variables in a custom class where something happens with the `SomeClass`:

```
class MyClass {
    SomeClass x;
public:
    MyClass() {
        x = SomeClass("foo", "bar");
    }
};
```

I'm not sure why, but for some reason the code seg faults whenever the  destructor is called on `MyClass`. I can easily avoid the problem by using `SomeClass *` but I'm curious as to what actually happens when variables are declared this way and not set.

Comment: You want `MyClass() : x("foo", "bar") {}`

Comment: What if you initialize it in an init list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, x is first initialized with a default constructor. Then you create a new object and assign it to the variable.

To avoid this double initialization, you should use initialization lists instead of assignment in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    SomeClass x;
public:
    MyClass() : x("foo", "bar") {}
};
```

Comment: What is the default constructor for `SomeClass`? No arguments are passed for the for the first declaration.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: If it is not defined, the compiler will generate one.

Comment: So, the compiler will try and call `SomeClass()` and if it finds nothing, it will create a constructor (`SomeClass()`) for it?

Comment: ...meaning that `SomeClass x;` and `SomeClass x = SomeClass();` are essentially the same?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a class variable by value, e.g.:

```
SomeClass x;
```

Then the non-parametric constructor is called (after the memory has been allocated to store the object `x`), assuming one exists. If you dot not declare any constructor for the class, then a non-parametric one is automatically generated by the compiler.

If your code crashes in the destructor, then you do not "fix" it by converting it to a pointer. In that case, you initialize the object by `new`, but then you never call the `delete` and the destructor is never called, resulting in a memory leak.